# How can I place a relative layout above a relative layout that's on the bottom of the main layout which is a custom listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I have a main layout that has a relative layout at the bottom. When I try to place a relative layout(id:rl) above this relative layout(id:relativelayout) it doesn't show up. But when I add a margin at the bottom it appears at the top of every item in the listview. Here is my xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#669900"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
   android:layout_above="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pass_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="#669900"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="#FF8800"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#0099CC" >     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please refine your question so may others understand easily. Which RelativeLayout are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a screenshot or a rough picture so that i can understand what u actually want to show up.....  u can also try to give gravity to the first relative layout as `PARENT_BOTTOM` and then give the other relative layout the parameter as `LAYOUT_ABOVE= "ID OF THE FIRST LAYOUT"`

Comment: how can I set the gravity to PARENT_ABOVE?

Comment: Sorry my typing mistakes.... i edited the answer.... please add a click to my answer if it is helpful to you...

Comment: that is what I did, have a look at my xml.

Comment: I tried to put your code in the XML i found that your relative layout with background "#0099CC" is at the bottom... so your frst condition req is done.... then when i remove your margin... it is still there above your relative layout (id:relativelayout) Please check your graphical layout again...

Comment: How are you judging that the "rl" is not above the "relativelayout" please provide screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#669900"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#0099CC" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locality"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pass_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="#669900"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/discount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="#FF8800"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what you wanted?

[image]

Comment: I just fixed the mistakes in your code. But if this is not what you wanted, you must explain it more clearly what exactly you wanted

Comment: FYI what i changed is, you must not user the '+' sign when you are using the id to set as reference. Like this android:Layout_Above:"@id/relativelayout" and first define the id before using it as a reference

Comment: @archie.logic I want to place the relativelayout(rl) above the relativelayout(relativelayout)

Comment: its not working this is a layout for everychild of a listview. It doesn't appear correctly in the list.

Comment: can you please paste a screen shot of what you are getting+ in the question.

Comment: the problem is that this is a child of a custom listview where in its not appearing properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16302/discussion-between-dinesh-venkata-and-archie-bpgc)